# Run a method every 5 minutes BuzzBox SDK

Tags: android

I need to execute a method every 5 minutes. My problem is where? or How? could be to start the application but did not realize that. Any recommendations?

Comment: You need to give more specific information about what you want to accomplish. What is the task of the method, is it a UI task, or a background task?

Comment: Update a database with webservice. I need data from my local database to update the external database every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how BuzzBox works but I would create a Runnable, then call your method inside it every 5 minutes; That of course uses postDelayed method.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do call your method here; every 5 minutes
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
    }

};

//you can use your handler anywhere you want like this

handler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 5000);
```

Comment: Handler works in your main thread. Don't play sounds with a handler.